# MySQL python connector UPDATE error: check right syntax to use near %s. What is going wrong?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, mysql-python

this should be relatively quick and easy:

When I run this in my python IDE

`mycursor.executemany("UPDATE table42 SET date = %s ", [('2020-05-11')])`

For some reason it is getting completely tripped up at the string placeholder (%s). The reason I am using executemany is because soon that string will be replace by a variable using `today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` so I need it to be more flexible.

The error is as follows: 
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1`

If someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `mycursor.executemany("UPDATE table42 SET date = %s ", [('2020-05-11',)])` work (note the comma after the date string)?

Comment: That did it, thank you! Do you happen to know why it needs the trailing comma?

Comment: also I would be happy to mark you as accepted for your answer if you put your reply in a separate answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a comma after the date string, so that the list is a list of tuples (it's commas that create tuples, not the parentheses).

```
mycursor.executemany("UPDATE table42 SET date = %s ", [('2020-05-11',)])
```

This is because the [DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) requires that parameters

> be provided as sequence or mapping

(Technically a string is a sequence, but here it would be of the wrong length.  mysql-connector rejects a string in any case I think, pymysql would accept one in this IIRC.  But making the parameters a tuple is definitely the most portable way to code this)

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem I am having now is that I can't get python to create a list with one single tuple and still keep the trailing comma. Concatenation doesn't do the trick as it adds to the string [('2020-05-11,')] instead of [('2020-05-11',)]

Comment: How is the list being created? Can you share the code?

Comment: Nevermind, just had to specify as a list of tuples using val4 = [(val3,)]

Comment: Thank you for all your help, if you're curious this is how I got it to work:

Comment: ```sql5 = "UPDATE spyopt_Today SET date = %s "
val3 = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
val4 = [(val3,)]

mycursor.execute(sql4)
mycursor.executemany(sql5, val4)```

Sorry I am not sure how to preserve the structure of code in the comments here.